# How to empty a table in mysql using Cronjob?

Tags: php, cron

I am using a Hosting with CPanel X, and i have a database which name: 'chat', and in this have a table 'chatmessenger'.
Now I want to know 
What query i must useempty(lean) this table automatically at 3AM daily with Cronjob.
sorry my English is not very well.
Thanks.

Comment: What are you looking for? How to set up the cron job? How to write the PHP script? What query you must use? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the tables size you might want to use

```
Truncate chatmessenger
```

Which is deleting large amounts of data way faster than a `delete` Query. You need to put this as a query in a php file, The cronjob then should be like

```
0 3 * * * php /path-to-your-file/file.php
```

**EDIT**

Put this in your php file, let's call it delete.php:

```
$sql = new mysqli ("localhost","your username to db", "your passwd to db", "db");
mysqli_query($sql, "truncate chatmessenger");
$sql->close();
```

(of course you need to change username, server and password... to your credentials.

Then add the cronjob as described with the path to your delete.php file.

Comment: sorry, can you help me what the content i must put in php file ? i am a beginer :(

Comment: see the edit, there you go

Comment: You're welcome! Please mark the answer as right when it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query will look like:

```
DELETE FROM chatmessenger
```

Or

```
TRUNCATE chatmessenger
```

Your cron job should look something like:

```
0   3   *   *   *   php /path/to/your/script.php
```